# Incorrect calculation with PID controller when simulating it

Tags: python, numpy, robotics, pid-controller

I am trying to learn to code a PID controller for my robot in 3D space (x, y, z). I decided to write a PID controller to control all three axis(velocity) all at once by putting them into a list. I am using the numpy library to make this program easier to calculate:

```
from time import monotonic
import numpy as np

_current_time = monotonic


class PID(object):

    def __init__(self, kp=1, ki=0.2, kd=0.2):
        self.kp = kp  # Constants (kp, ki, kd)
        self.ki = ki
        self.kd = kd

        # Storing the errors
        self.p_errors = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=float)  # Contains the proportional error for each dimension
        self.i_errors = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=float)  # Contains the integral error for each dimension
        self.d_errors = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=float)  # Contains the integral error for each dimension
        self.last_error = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=float)  # Contains the last calculated error for each dimension
        self.time = _current_time()  # Current monotonic time
        self.current = None  # Current velocity in all 3 dimension (set to None)
        self.set_point = None  # Desired velocity in all 3 dimension (set to None)
        self.__min__ = -20  # Minimum output (negative means the robot wants to go backward)
        self.__max__ = 20   # Maximum output

    def set_value(self, current: list, set_point: list):
        self.current = np.array(current, dtype=float)
        self.set_point = np.array(set_point, dtype=float)

    def calculate_error(self):
        now = _current_time()  # Get current monotonic time
        delta_error = self.set_point - self.current  # Calculates error between desired velocity and current velocity in all 3 dimensions
        delta_time = now - self.time if now - self.time else 1e-16  # Calculate change in time (if it is 0, then return time as 1e-16)
        self.time = now  # saving the current monotonic time
        return delta_error, delta_time

    def control_loop(self):
        delta_error, delta_time = self.calculate_error()  # Value for change in error and change in time
        
        # Classical PID controller formula implemented in Python using NumPy library
        self.p_errors = delta_error * delta_time
        self.i_errors += delta_error * delta_time
        self.d_errors = (delta_error - self.last_error) / delta_time
        self.last_error = delta_error
        outputs = self.p_errors * self.kp + self.i_errors * self.ki + self.d_errors * self.kd
        self.current = np.array(outputs, dtype=float)  # Setting current to the calculate PID output, thus closer to setpoint value ***This line causes some error that I just can't figure out
        return outputs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pid = PID()
    pid.set_value([0, 0, 0], [0, 10, 0])  # Testing PID controller 
    while True:
        x = pid.control_loop()
        print(x)
```

The line `self.current = np.array(outputs, dtype=float)` is causing issue for some reason. My reason for putting this line in is to help simulate the PID controller and see if it works properly. Essentially, I wanted to set the current value to the PID output, thus it is closer to the setpoint value. However, when I ran the program it prints out number so large that NumPy had to convert it to `nan`. Without that line, it seems that the PID controller works just fine and without issue, so perhaps it is the way I am testing this software that is the main issue here. If that's case, is there a better way to test out the current program I have right now?

Edited code which works, but never overshoots for some reason:

```
from time import monotonic
import numpy as np

_current_time = monotonic


class PID(object):

    def __init__(self, kp=0.3, ki=0.5, kd=0.002):
        self.kp = kp  # Constants (kp, ki, kd)
        self.ki = ki
        self.kd = kd

        # Storing the errors
        self.p_errors = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=float)  # Contains the proportional error for each dimension
        self.i_errors = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=float)  # Contains the integral error for each dimension
        self.d_errors = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=float)  # Contains the integral error for each dimension
        self.last_error = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=float)  # Contains the last calculated error for each dimension
        self.time = _current_time()  # Current monotonic time
        self.current = None  # Current velocity in all 3 dimension (set to None)
        self.set_point = None  # Desired velocity in all 3 dimension (set to None)
        self.output = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=float)
        self.__min__ = -20  # Minimum output (negative means the robot wants to go backward)
        self.__max__ = 20   # Maximum output

    def set_value(self, current: list, set_point: list):
        self.current = np.array(current, dtype=float)
        self.set_point = np.array(set_point, dtype=float)

    def calculate_error(self):
        now = _current_time()  # Get current monotonic time
        delta_error = self.set_point - self.current  # Calculates error between desired velocity and current velocity in all 3 dimensions
        self.time = now  # saving the current monotonic time
        return delta_error

    def control_loop(self):
        delta_error = self.calculate_error()  # Value for change in error and change in time
        # Classical PID controller formula implemented in Python using NumPy library
        self.p_errors = delta_error
        self.i_errors += delta_error * 0.05
        self.d_errors = (delta_error - self.last_error) / 0.05
        self.last_error = delta_error
        outputs = self.p_errors * self.kp + self.i_errors * self.ki + self.d_errors * self.kd
        outputs = np.where(outputs > self.__max__, self.__max__, outputs)  # Replacing terms too big
        outputs = np.where(outputs < self.__min__, self.__min__, outputs)  # Replacing terms too small
        self.current = outputs
        return outputs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pid = PID()
    pid.set_value([0, 0, 0], [0, -10, 0])  # Testing PID controller
    while True:
        print(pid.control_loop())
```

Comment: Your problem is an interesting one. I believe that instead of testing the output within the control_loop function, you could create a separate function to handle this. Similarly, instead of passing the P, I, D parameters in the constructor, you could assign them in a special method inside your PID class and perform some profiling of the algorithm outside (during the main execution) and see the evolution of the output. Perhaps tuning your control might come handy. For that purpose review the Siegler-Nichols method for tuning PID controllers

Comment: @DanielMelendrez I tested out my PID controller again, but this time without the derivative term and it appeared to work fine. The output without the derivative was able to reach the setpoint relatively fast in a second or two. However, the moment I add the derivative term and set it to like a number of 0.01, the output becomes infinitely large. I probably didn't tune it right just yet, but I think there is also some issue with the speed at which this PID controller is going at because the change in time is almost always 1e-16. Should I sleep the function for a few seconds for better results?

Comment: Also, I am not sure why, but whenever I test it, the output never overshoots. Though I believe it is the method which I am testing it, which prevents it from ever really overshooting.